# How to get "newly added photos to an album" in facebook news feed using Graph Api

Tags: facebook, fbconnect, facebook-graph-api

I am getting facebook news feed using

> News feed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=MyAccessToken

I am getting all news feed object.But in news feeds  object with type "photo",

I am getting only last added picture url (If user is added some photos to that album).

But how to get news feeds like "Jack added 3 new photos to the album MyApp Photos."

I want to get 3 photos in that album , if user added any photos to an album. I googled a lot.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright - this is a little bit hacky but I can't see any otherway. In your news feed you will see an item along the lines of:

```
{
         "id": "123456789_3453453455345334",
         "from": {
            "name": "A Friend",
            "id": "123456789"
         },
         "to": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "A Friend",
                  "id": "123456789"
               }
            ]
         },
         "picture": "PICTURE_URL",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3453453455345334&set=a.10151233554845639.123456.123456789&type=1",
         "name": "Mobile Uploads",
         "caption": "10 new photos",
         "icon": "ICON_URL",
         "type": "photo",
         "object_id": "3453453455345334",
         "application": {
            "name": "Facebook for iPhone",
            "id": "6628568379"
         },
         "created_time": "2000-06-29T19:56:50+0000",
         "updated_time": "2001-06-29T19:56:50+0000"
      },
```

The key in there is the link url, which contains:

set=a.**10151233554845639**.123456.123456789

The first number, after the a, appears to be the album id. We can therefore get the photos from the album by querying:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10151233554845345/photos?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you share a photo that already exists on Facebook then it appears with an extra property called properties:

```
"properties": [
            {
               "name": "By",
               "text": "A Friend",
               "href": "http://www.facebook.com/a.friend"
            }
         ],
```

If you share a photo on your wall this is actually an upload and so will not include the `properties` property

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But if a user simply share a photo in their profile, we will get the feed like this only.But "Jack added 3 new photos to the album MyApp Photos." notification comes in news feed when we adding new photos to album (Without make a post..It will come automatically in news feed). So how can we identify this feed is facebook generated ?

Comment: The above excerpt is from the /home/ channel. Do you want the result from the /feed/ channel? I'm not sure what you mean by 'Facebook generated', the above excerpt IS Facebook generated

Comment: When am adding a photo to my album or when am creating a new album , that event will come automatically in news feed. When we share a photo also another news feed will be created..   We are getting both news feeds with a type "photo".My question is how to distinguish these two types of news feeds ?

Comment: Check my edited response - I think this is what you mean. I just went through the four flows. Upload a new album, upload a new picture to an album, share an existing picture, share a new picture. If you share a new picture that is actually an upload to wall photos. Therefore the only way to distinguish is if you share an existing photo in which case see the answer

Comment: @BeRecursive  Ya..thats the only way to differentiate different "photo" news feeds..Hope Facebook will document about this problem/issue.Thanks for your answer..I was thinking about this problem for 2 days...Finally found a solution..Thanks once again..

Comment: And i got 3 photos from an album by calling  "https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos?limit=3&offset=0&access_token=MY_ACCESSTOKEN&fields=picture"